# 2d array search optimization

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

I wrote a code in order to find 3 repeated elements in a row/column in 2d array.

```
private static bool SearchInRows(int[,] matrix)
{
    int count = 1;
    int repeatElement = int.MaxValue;

    //Search in rows
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        repeatElement = matrix[i, 0];

        for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (repeatElement == matrix[i, j])
            {
                count++;
                if (count >= 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Repeated elements are in positions i:{i}, j:{j - 2}, {j - 1}, {j}");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                repeatElement = matrix[i, j];
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
private static bool SearchInCols(int[,] matrix)
{
    int count = 1;
    int repeatElement = int.MaxValue;

    //Search in cols
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        repeatElement = matrix[0, j];

        for (int i = 1; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (repeatElement == matrix[i, j])
            {
                count++;
                if (count >= 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Repeated elements are in positions j:{j}, i:{i-2}, {i-1}, {i}");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                repeatElement = matrix[i, j];
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works fine, but I will do something like this:

```
while (!SearchInRows(matrix) && !SearchInCols(matrix))
{
    SearchInRows(matrix);
    SearchInCols(matrix);
    //modify the matrix
}
```

And I am wondering, if I can use something to improve the performance of my code, like adding the Task.Run on each method or something  (I split the method in cols and rows for that).

Comment: Well, a huge performance increase would be to "cache" the result, currently your calling `SearchInRows` and `SearchInCols` twice in every iteration where as you could be calling each only once and save the result in a local variable to reuse

Comment: You can combine them into one method and compare for each selected element the element to the right and bottom in the 2d array, and if they match do it again. Since you are currently iterating twice over every element you can half the amount of elements you are iterating over...

Comment: @dan-kli Okay, but if the element at the bottom/right isn't the same, how am I excluding them from the search?

Comment: You take the current element and hold it. Then you compare it to the element on the right, and if they match, compare it to the element on the right again. Then you can compare it to the element below, and then again if they match. These are 2 separate functionalities (and could be put into their own methods). If neither functionality returns true, you move on to the next element. What do you mean by excluding them from the search?

Comment: @dan-kli nvm, I think I shouldn't remove them, cause they can form a row repeat, sorry for bothering, and thanks for help

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. Well you could hold two arrays SkippedColumnCells and SkippedRowCells, where you add array locations with such cells and skip their comparison, but it will hardly improve performance, since you will now have additional comparisons with the arrays and skip certain cell comparisons. Still I think the implementation I described is a lot more performant even if you check some cells twice, since you iterate twice over every cell (and with the way you call your methods with the while function actually 4 times).

Comment: ^the reply was to your previous comment. I think it is true what you said previously, it would theoretically possible to skip checks for the specific case that you already had 2 repeating numbers and the third one does not match, but that information has to also be stored and called from somewhere, which like I said kinda removes performance again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more performant solutions to your problem, since your functions essentially require you to iterate twice over each element (once for the columns, once for the rows). And with the way you call your functions, you have even more iterations.

This is a more efficient solution I came up with, but there might be better ones. Basically, I only iterate once over each element and check if the next two elements in the column and row match. For example, lets look at the following 8x8 2d array. I iterate once over each element in the red box and check if the next two elements in the row/column match. This leaves me with two rows and two columns unchecked, which I have to check individually.

[image]

Here is the code:

```csharp
private static void FindThreeRepeatedElements(int[,] matrix)
{
    // iterate once trough each element (red box) and check
    // if the next 2 elements in the row / column match
    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0) - 2; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix.GetLength(1) - 2; column++)
        {
            CheckRow(matrix, row, column);
            CheckColumn(matrix, row, column);
        }
    }

    // check the last remaining 2 rows
    CheckRow(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 2, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3);
    CheckRow(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 1, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3);

    // check the last remaining 2 columns
    CheckColumn(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3, matrix.GetLength(0) - 2);
    CheckColumn(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3, matrix.GetLength(0) - 1);
}

private static void CheckRow(int[,] matrix, int row, int column)
{
    int element = matrix[row, column];
    if (element == matrix[row, column + 1] && element == matrix[row, column + 2])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Three repeated elements with value {element} are found in row {row} at the positions: [{row}, {column}], [{row}, {column + 1}], [{row}, {column + 2}]");
    }
}

private static void CheckColumn(int[,] matrix, int row, int column)
{
    int element = matrix[row, column];
    if(element == matrix[row + 1, column] && element == matrix[row + 2, column])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Three repeated elements with value {element} are found in column {column} at the positions: [{row}, {column}], [{row + 1}, {column}], [{row + 2}, {column}]");
    }
}
```

As you pointed out in the comments a while ago, there are some cases where the checking of some elements can be skipped, since they already have been checked previously. For example, if we look at the 8x8 2d array again, after comparing the elements in the blue box, we see that the first two elements match (both have value 7), so we check if the third element also has value 7, which fails (it has value 4). Now we already know that we can skip the checks for the next three elements in the row (orange box), because when we get to the elements with value 7, 4 and 5 we already did the comparison of the first two elements in the previous iteration.

[image]

I modified the code from above to skip those comparisons, which leaves us with more code but technically less comparisons (not sure if it is actually much more performant). In this example, the bool *_skipNextRowCheck* would be true after doing the comparisons in the blue box, which would completely skip checking if the 3 elements in the orange box have equal values.

Here is the modified code:

```csharp
private static bool _skipNextRowCheck = false;
private static bool _skipNextColumnCheck = false;

private static void FindThreeRepeatedElementsWithSkips(int[,] matrix)
{
    // iterate trough each element and check
    // if the next 2 elements in the row / column match
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0) - 2; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix.GetLength(1) - 2; column++)
        {
            CheckRowWithSkips(matrix, row, column);
            CheckColumnWithSkips(matrix, row, column);
        }
    }

    // check the last remaining 2 rows
    CheckRowWithSkips(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 2, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3);
    CheckRowWithSkips(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 1, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3);

    // check the last remaining 2 columns
    CheckColumnWithSkips(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3, matrix.GetLength(0) - 2);
    CheckColumnWithSkips(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0) - 3, matrix.GetLength(0) - 1);
}

private static void CheckRowWithSkips(int[,] matrix, int row, int column)
{
    if(_skipNextRowCheck)
    {
        _skipNextRowCheck = false;
        return;
    }

    int element = matrix[row, column];
    if (element == matrix[row, column + 1])
    {
        if(element == matrix[row, column + 2])
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Three repeated elements with value {element} are found in row {row} at the positions: [{row}, {column}], [{row}, {column + 1}], [{row}, {column + 2}]");
        }
        else
        {
            _skipNextRowCheck = true;
        }
    }
}

private static void CheckColumnWithSkips(int[,] matrix, int row, int column)
{
    if (_skipNextColumnCheck)
    {
        _skipNextColumnCheck = false;
        return;
    }

    int element = matrix[row, column];
    if (element == matrix[row + 1, column])
    {
        if(element == matrix[row + 2, column])
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Three repeated elements with value {element} are found in column {column} at the positions: [{row}, {column}], [{row + 1}, {column}], [{row + 2}, {column}]");
        }
        else
        {
            _skipNextColumnCheck = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a main function with the pictured 2d array, simply copy the main function and all the other functions into one *Program* class to try it out:

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] matrix = new int[8, 8] 
    { 
        { 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8 },
        { 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 9, 3, 8 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8 },
        { 1, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 7, 5, 9, 9, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 9, 9, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9 },
    };

    Console.WriteLine("\nSearching for three repeated elements in the 2d array:");
    FindThreeRepeatedElements(matrix);

    Console.WriteLine("\nSearching for three repeated elements in the 2d array, and skipping unneccessary comparisons:");
    FindThreeRepeatedElementsWithSkips(matrix);
}
```